# TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer, uic

what's wrong with my code? I'm trying to connect my UI file with python. I'm almost sure about everything, but I can't define what the wrong is.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

ui = loadUiType('main.ui')


class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUI(self)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exex_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The error is caused because you're not using your ui class correctly and there is a also typo in `__init__`. Change to `ui = loadUiType('main.ui')[0]` and `self.setupUi(self)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the 'inheritance' style of UI file loading is supposed to work. However, this should do what you want:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi('main.ui', self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem, because it does exactly the same thing as the OP's example (only using different syntax). However, it will at least give a less cryptic error message: i.e. `TypeError: Wrong base class of toplevel widget`.

Comment: @ekhumoro It runs fine on my machine. If you get the above error, it probably means that your UI file is invalid (probably wrong widget class, needs to match `MainApp`)

Comment: That's because you aren't attempting to reproduce the actual problem. See my comment on the OPs question.

Comment: @ekhumoro are you sure? I created an UI with a single `QMainWindow`, which matches the class of `MainApp`. However running OP's code still fails, while my code works.

Comment: There are some typos in the OP's example which were confusing matters. Once those are fixed, the other problems go away.